How to store and mapped XCM message on relaychain
I want to send a message (including name, age, gender, etc.) from a parachain to a relay chain. Then, I want to store and map that data with the particular account number on relaychain. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve that?

This seems not a valid question. I'd suggest to split to
1, How to use storage on substrate
2, How to communicate use xcm
